# RDP from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, remote, desktop, rdp

Today I wanted to make my RDP from Windows to OpenSuse. After successful setup and configuration I can connect to my RDP but can't make any changes or see any views on OpenSuse desktop. When I login as local VM (not RDP) I see folders on desktop and can make changes. Is there any ability to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

For viewing desktop , You have some way:

1. `VNC`
2. set `DISPLAY` variable in your terminal.

   **NOTE:** You don't have RDP in Linux as RDP server.